# How to update the datatype of alternative key once its created?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I want to changed the datatype of a column marked as alternate key.

I changed the datatype in the code and created new migration script but the script throws error.

```
   public class Person
    {
        [Key]
        public int PersonId { get; set; }
        public int Email { get; set; }
    }

public class TestEntities:DbContext
    {
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data Source=(LocalDb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=ff;Integrated Security=SSPI;");
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().HasAlternateKey(a => a.Email);
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
        public DbSet<Person> Person { get; set; }
    }
```

Here Email(int datatype in code which is coded mistakenly during development) needs to be unique. So I used fluent api to make in unique.
Then I created initial migration script and ran the script
The table is created with email as unique key constraint
The Table as this point doesnot have any rows.
Now I corrected the datatype of email  to string.
Then I created second migration script and when i try to run I get the following error

The object 'AK_Person_Email' is dependent on column 'Email'.
ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN Email failed because one or more objects access this column.

How do you update the datatype.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change datatype of a column that is included in an alternate key (or primary key, foreign key or index). To achieve your goal, drop the alternate key, change datatype of the column and create the alternate key again.